# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataKeys

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an existing web application. I'm receiving some front-end errors that are fired for just one known user. The log says:

> [2014-05-19 18:40:05] frontend.ERROR: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataKeys {"file":"undefined","line":"13","browser":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.76.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.4 Safari/537.76.4","page":"aPageFromTheSite"} []

This error is fired from different pages on the site.

I've tried to search the variable dataKeys:

```
grep -r "dataKeys" ./
```

but no results are found. I wonder where could it come from, since I'm not able to reproduce the error. I've also "googled", but no relevant results are found. Any idea of what it can be due to?

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins in their browser and then tested the site? Could be an error from something they have installed.

Comment: @JamieDixon - Well, I'm not able to do that. This is just a specific registered user (a client), and I shouldn't disturb him with it. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm seeing this error alog in my new relic javascript error tracking.  I'm thinking perhaps it's one of the ad networks (google or infolinks, etc)

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error with same OS and same script line (13).

Comment: Might be worth checking if "the client" is not running in incognito mode (wrong approach to auto-clear their cache) or some local adblockers (or similar pests) are preventing some routines to execute properly.

Comment: I've come across this same issue reported from a user also. "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataKeys"

It too was Safari 7.0.4 and was reported on line number 13.

Comment: Must be nice to work somewhere that has error logs so clean that you can bother working on a single issue that just a single users is having. lol :)

Comment: I suspect a poor safari extension / maybe adware or something.

Comment: We've recently added Raven.js and Sentry and I've just seen this, 2 errors in the last hour, again with message: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dataKeys`, stack trace: `undefined ? in ? at line 13`, browser: `Safari 7.0.4`. Very intriguing!

Comment: I had a user of ours claim that disabling an installed Safari extension named "gophoto.it" resolved this error message.

Comment: GoPhoto.it seems to be malware that inserts ads on web pages. I'm reaching out to one of our users now to see if it's the cause of the errors.

Answer (score 2):

This can come from a third party script or because of a Javascript function trying to reference a variable before the page is properly loaded.

Hard to tell without looking at the code but since you searched the server for the string I would guess it's a referenced script.

Could be jquery, too if it's not present on the server and imported from an external source.

When a script on the page references a jquery variable before jquery is loaded, such errors can occur.
That's why one should always use $(document).ready(function() to prevent such errors.

Comment: jQuery contains no references to 'dataKeys', in my case I am not loading it from CDN and is present on my server.

Comment: Can you find out which script exactly fired this exception? And the corresponding code on that line? It's quite dubious...

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask: Are you the author of the code? If so, check if you dynamically add Javascript to your page because that needs to be eval'd.